# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Error in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client I'm getting this error. I did some study and I think it's because of more than one callbacks but I'm unable to solve this issue. Please help me fix this issue. I'm attaching herewith my routes.js code. Any help will be highly appreciable.  Thank you.

> Here's my routes.js code

```
const {
   con,g
   sessionStore
 } = require('./config/db');
const { route } = require('./routes/auth');
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
      const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
      var img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
               var sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
               var query = con.query(sql, [username, title, state, category, img_name, description], function(err) {
                  console.log(err)
                 if (!err) {
                   res.redirect('show/' + username);
                 }
                 else {
                  message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
                  res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
                }
               }); 
            }); 
          
   } 
}
   else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
       console.log(err)
      if(result.length <= 0){
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
     }else{
      res.redirect('/places');
     }
     res.render('show', {data:result, message: message});
   });
  
};
 
exports.places=function (req,res){
   let message = '';
   var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
       console.log(err)
       if(result.length <= 0)
         message = "places not found!";
   res.render('places.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to convert all function calls with callbacks into async function with `Promise`. That way your code would be more sequential and you easily fix your issue. And avoid SQL injection by inserting a user input into SQL query by concatenating strings. Learn how to use query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your show function you execute a database query, inside the  callback you have an if else statement with a res.render and a res.redirect. So one way or the other a result is sent. So you cannot send a result when the if statement is completed.
Remove this `res.render('show', {data:result, message: message});`. line and you are good to go!

Comment: I removed the res.render('show', {data:result, message: message}); satement written after the if else part , but on removing it new.ejs file directly redirects to places.ejs instead of redirecting to show.ejs page

Comment: Because of this only I added res.render there

Comment: That is because your query probably has no results. I think that was the problem in your other question?

Comment: yes, but I'm able to insert data in the database.

Comment: Ah I think I finally see it. In sql you cannot use the equal sing: = You should use LIKE. ```SELECT * FROM nt_data` WHERE username LIKE' "+username+"'```. And don't use a variable in a string like that. Use it like you did in your new function ```SELECT * FROM nt_data` WHERE username LIKE ?", [username] ```